# Regex is not compliant for Safari (lookbehind)

Tags: javascript, regex, safari, compatibility, regex-lookarounds

I have a problem making my regular expression Safari compatible.

Unfortunately, the lookbehind functionality cannot be used in JS on Safari:
https://caniuse.com/?search=lookbehind

That's why I have to convert my regex to one that is doing the same, but without the lookbehind.

Here is the regular expression I use with lookbehind:

```
((?<!\\)}})
```

The result would look like (bold is the match):

> %{{Hello this is a test with escaping \}} and the end should be here:**}}**

Please note that \}} must not be matched.

If you want to try, you can use the following link: https://regexr.com/6qq8k

Has anybody an idea how this could be done, without a lookbehind?

Of course, I have already searched for a solution on the internet before. After more than one day of searching, I want to try it on StackOverflow.

The problem is, that I'm using a JS-Library (codemirror), where I have to pass the correct regular expression. That means I cannot modify the matched result afterward, which excludes somehow all solutions I found.

So I need a regular expression that excludes without any additional JS-Code the not needed chars and finds the correct matches.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [javascript regex lookbehind safari](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+regex+lookbehind+safari+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: Hi @Andreas,
thanks for the answer. Of course, I have already searched for a solution on the Internet before. The problem is, that I'm using a JS-Library, where I have to pass the correct regular expression.

That means I cannot modify the matched result afterward. So I need a regular expression that excludes without any additional JS-Code the not needed chars and finds the correct matches.

Comment: _"The problem is, that I'm using a JS-Library, ..."_ -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Add relevant information in the question itself. _"I have already searched for a solution..."_ -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) -> Show _in the question itself_ that you've done (enough) research and/or what you've tried to solve this on your own.

Comment: One more idea: **If** in practice your `}}` will always be after a letter (not spaces or special characters like parentheses, colon or newline), you could use `\b}}` :) If any character can be in front of it, then I'm pretty sure you're out of luck :/

Comment: Hey @Jay, thanks for trying it. But looks like I'm out of luck ^^ You can write everything in front of `}}`.

Comment: @MarcelFrank Wait, one more thing: I noticed you used seemingly useless parentheses in your expression. Does your JS library need `}}` to be in group 1 or to be entire match? Because if you need it in group 1, then `(?:[^\\]|^)(}})` should work. (first group is non-capturing because of `?:`, so won't count and your `}}` will be group 1) https://regex101.com/r/gkxty2/1

Comment: Hey @Jay, as I know it must be the whole match and I'm not able to select the group that should be used. But I will check if it is possible with the library (codemirror) to define which group should be used. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0):

From your question is not clear what you want to accomplish besides identifying a trailing `}}` pattern that is not escaped, this without using negative lookbehind.

Here is a solution with example that makes assumptions:

- you have a string with one or more `%{{...}}` patterns
- you want to apply some transformation with each pattern
- the example replaces each `%{{...}}` pattern with `<b>...</b>` bold tags

```js
[
  "%{{Hello, escaping \\}}, and end here:}}",
  "aaa %{{Hello, escaping \\}}, and end here:}} zzz",
  "aaa %{{Hello, escaping \\}}, and end here:}} bbb %{{Another hello}} zzz"
].forEach(str => {
  console.log(str.replace(/(%\{\{)(.*?[^\\])(\}\})/g, function(m, p1, p2, p3) {
    return '<b>' + p2 + '</b>'
  }));
});
```

Output:

```
<b>Hello, escaping \}}, and end here:</b>
aaa <b>Hello, escaping \}}, and end here:</b> zzz
aaa <b>Hello, escaping \}}, and end here:</b> bbb <b>Another hello</b> zzz
```

Explanation of regex:

- `(%\{\{)` -- capture group #1: `%{{` pattern
- `(.*?[^\\])` -- capture group #2: non-greedy scan over any text until just before `}}`, excluding `\}}`
- `(\}\})` -- capture group #3: `}}` pattern
- `/g` -- global, e.g. process more than once

**UPDATE 2022-11-01:**

If you want to extract multiple handlebars from a string use this:

```
"aaa %{{Hello, escaping \\}}, and end here:}} bbb %{{Another hello}} zzz".match(/%\{\{.*?[^\\]\}\}/g);
```

...which will return two matches:

```
[ '%{{Hello, escaping \\}}, and end here:}}', '%{{Another hello}}' ]
```

Explanation of regex:

- `%\{\{` -- start of handlebar (`%{{`)
- `.*?` -- non-greedy scan
- `[^\\]` -- a single char that is not a backslash
- `\}\}` -- end of handlebar (`}}`)

Comment: @Marcel Frank: Does the answer address your needs? If so would you care to accept it? If not, add some more details to your question.

Comment: Nope. Please read the last part of the question: So I need a regular expression that excludes without any additional JS-Code the not needed chars and finds the correct matches.

Comment: @MarcelFrank: I am still not clear about our question. I updated my answer from what I understand you are asking for.

Comment: Hey @Peter Thoeny, as described in the question, my result should only be the closing braces that are not escaped. Not the text around or inside the braces.